# subsonic 3.0.0.3 activeRecord Between

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic, subsonic3

Hi im using subsonic 3.0.0.3 activeRecord but cant seems to figure between !

```
select * from orders where orderdate between startdate, enddate;
```

have tried `IQueryable<orders> myOrders = order.All().Where(x => x.order_date).isBetweenAnd`

help much appreciated, please make note of version number, and that any answers actually work for that version
and activeRecord.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
order.All().Where(x => x.order_date >= Min_Date && x.order_date <= Max_Date);
```